# Disocrd.js [object Object]

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i am making a Discord Beat saber bot with scoresaber api: node-scoresaber

And i get [object Object] in return, i have no idea why is it, maybe because i am doing it wrong

```
if(msg.content === "!toprequests"){
        const topRequests = await saber.getTopRequests();
        if (topRequests[0]) {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Top Rank Requests")
            .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/yVrRltU.png")
            .setColor("#8742f5")
            .setDescription(`
Name of the song: ${await topRequests[0].get().name}
            `)
            msg.channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
```

I've even tried topRequests.name, topRequests[1].get().name without await i just don't know why it does this
Heres a link to github of the npm: https://github.com/SpikeHD/node-scoresaber

Comment: Oops, i accindetly typed 1 in: topRequests[1].get().name instead of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript [object Object] is a string representation of an object. To see the contents of an object, you should print the object to the console using console.log() or convert the object to a string.

Edit: Looks like you can't get the name right after the promise function here is how your code should look:

```js
if(msg.content === "!toprequests"){
        const topRequests = await saber.getTopRequests();
        if (topRequests[0]) {
            let name = await topRequests[0].get().name;
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Top Rank Requests")
                .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/yVrRltU.png")
                .setColor("#8742f5")
                .setDescription(`Name of the song: ${name}`)
            msg.channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: now it says: undefined ive printed into the console it pops up all of the properties like name, votes ETC

Comment: Let me try it out and I'll get back to you